# How I can save the moment as timestamp when these lines runs?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, drupal, timestamp

```
  $status = db_insert('errors')
            ->fields( array(
              'timestamp' => ???????,
              'wid' => $wid,))
            ->execute();
```

I want when this line of code running to save the timestamp that will be the moment that this lines will run.. Could someone help me on how to do that thing?

Comment: the time() function should return a timestamp for you, then you can store it in a variable and set that as the value of timestamp in the array

Comment: What is the datatype of `timestamp` column ?

Comment: the datatype is int... what it must be?

Comment: if its `int` then you may use php `time()` function. Or better would be to have datatype as `datetime` or `timestamp` and you will have `date('Y-m-d H:i:s')` which will make your query easier while to do some select on the table using date range etc.

Comment: when i run my code without timestamp it works perfect but when I insert time() or REQUEST_TIME my code do not do nothing and i do not know why!!!timestamp is 'int'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you literally want the moment that the line was saved, use `time()`.

```
$status = db_insert('errors')
  ->fields(array(
    'timestamp' => time(),
    'wid' => $wid,
  ));
```

If you want to save a few processor ticks, and the value is acceptable, you can use Drupal's [`REQUEST_TIME`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/constant/REQUEST_TIME/7) constant (which is set to the current timestamp at the beginning of each request).

```
$status = db_insert('errors')
  ->fields(array(
    'timestamp' => REQUEST_TIME,
    'wid' => $wid,
  ));
```

Comment: when i run my code without timestamp it works perfect but when I insert time() or REQUEST_TIME my code do not do nothing and i do not know why!!!timestamp is 'int'

Comment: You're missing a call to `execute()`, other than that the code is fine

Comment: if i run without time() it insert the values if i put time() nothing is inserted

Comment: You're gonna need to be a lot more specific. "do not run" means nothing

Comment: I don't know what you're expecting me to say - you said the column is an integer, and time() returns an integer. It must work, or part of your explanation is wrong